# Error HH23: You are trying to initialize a project inside an existing Hardhat project

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I've been working on a Hardhat project for sometime.
After a while, when I run `npx hardhat init` I get the error below:

Error HH23: You are trying to initialize a project inside an existing Hardhat project.

My previous command was

```
`npm install --save-dev hardhat`
```

Why this error occur?

Comment: It means you already have a hardhat.config.js file in your directory

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue while trying to initialize a new Hardhat project using the npx hardhat init command. The error message (Error HH23) indicated that I was attempting to initialize a project within an existing Hardhat project, and it pointed to the existing hardhat.config.js file in the parent directory.

Directory -> D:\web3practice\Twitter-Dapp>

After investigating, I realized that the parent directory (web3practice) already had a hardhat.config.js file. To resolve this, I removed the hardhat.config.js file from the parent directory and retried the npx hardhat init command in the intended subdirectory (Twitter-Dapp). This resolved the issue, and I was able to successfully initialize the new Hardhat project.

I hope this explanation helps anyone facing a similar problem. If you have any questions or need further clarification, feel free to ask.